# Change how many approved comments must user have

Tags: comments

Wordpress has a default option that checks if user has an approved comment before.

How do i change this number to a higher limit so that u**sers must have more than one approved comment** to publish future comments without approval.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`pre_comment_approved`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_comment_approved/) filter to modify the approval status for the `$approved = 1` case, excluding the post author and users with `moderate_comments` capability.

Then set it to `0` if the commenter has fewer than `2` *approved* comments.

Note that the *approved* value can also be `'spam'` or `'trash'`.

Comment: Hi, birgire thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining with a code snippet please?

Comment: The code in [`wp_allow_comment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_allow_comment/) and [`check_comment()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/check_comment/) is helpful to see what kind of queries you could use.